# Vehicle counting based on classification (cars,buses,trucks)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I am currently working on vehicle platooning for which I need to design a code in python opencv for counting the number of vehicles based on the classification.The input is a real time traffic video.
The aim is finding an average size "x" for the bounding box and say that for cars its "x", for buses its "3x" and so on.Based on size of "x" or multiples of "x", determine the classification.Is there any possible way I can approach this problem statement?

Comment: You can, for example by doing some research. There are ton's of articles out there already. not specifically "platooning" but you  probably can derive this from the distances of the vehicles to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Haar-cascades** are a good method, however training them takes a lot of time as well as effort.
You can get a lot of trained cascades file online.
Second approach could be of **getting the contours** from the image and then proceeding forward.

```
 - Original image
 - Smooth the image so that you will get an image without edges.
 - (Original image- Smooth image) to get the edges
 - Get Contours from image
```

Comment: Thank you for the above mentioned method as a solution for the problem.

Comment: I have done something similar here.
You can refer to my github page
https://github.com/akshaybahadur21/ImageSegmentation

Comment: I am afraid to say, but if objects of interests are very less compared to what is observed in the scene, this approach results into a lot more false positives. This is irrespective of what you use as a classification method.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on almost similar problem.

Easiest way is to train a `Haar-cascade` on the vehicles of similar size.

You will have to train multiple cascades based on the number of categories.

Data for the cascade can be downloaded from any used car selling site using some browser plugin.

The negative sets pretty much depend on the context in which this solution will be used.

This also brings the issue that, if you plan to do this on a busy street, there are going to be many unforeseen scenarios. For example, pedestrian walking in the FoV. Also, FoV needs to be fixed, especially the distance from which objects are observed. Trail and error is the only way to achieve sweet-spot for the thresholds, if any.

Now I am going to suggest something outside the scope of the question you asked.

Though this is purely image processing based approach, you can turn the problem on its face, and ask a question  'Why' classification is needed? Depending on the use-case, more often than not, it will be possible to train a deep reinforcement learning agent. It will solve the problem without getting into lot of manual work.

Let me know in case of a specific issues.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.